# How to make headerTemplate condition in kendo grid work

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-grid

Look at field SourceStr --> headerTemplate and you will see that I'm trying to display two buttons on condition. If condition is true there will be one button and if condition is false there will be different button. The code example that I attached actually works, but when instead 'true' or 'false' I'm trying to put variable with boolean value - it won't work, instead it will remove everything from my table and it will be empty. 
Pls advice how I can use variable in my condition, thank you!

$scope.gridOptions = {

```
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({ pageSize: 50 }),

        columns: [{

            field: "Quantity",

            title: culture.stringConst.Quantity,

            width: "4em",

            template: "#if (Xpnd == true) { #<div class='quantity-row'><button class='quantity-row-button' ng-click='button(dataItem)'><span class='quantity-arrow'>❯</span></button><span class='quantity-row-span'>#=Quantity#</span></div> # }" +
                "else if(Xpnd == false) { #<div class='quantity-row'><button class='quantity-row-button' ng-click='button(dataItem)'><span class='quantity-downarrow'>❯</span></button><span class='quantity-row-span'>#=Quantity#</span></div> # }" +
                "else if (Child) { #<div class='child-marker'><span>⚠</span></div>#} #",

            headerTemplate: "<span class='aecolumn-name'>Quantity</span><button class='panel-button' disabled><img class='filter-icon'/></button>"

        }, {

            field: "TimeStamp",

            title: culture.stringConst.Time,

            width: "9em",

            template: "#if (!Child) {#<span style='font-weight: bold;'>#=kendo.toString(TimeStamp,'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff')#</span>#} else { #<span>#=kendo.toString(TimeStamp,'M/d/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff')#</span># }#",

            headerTemplate: "<span class='aecolumn-name'>TimeStamp</span><button class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(1)'><img src='Images/filter-icon.png' class='filter-icon'/></button>"

        }, {

            field: "SourceStr",

            title: culture.stringConst.Source,

            width: "15em",

            template: "#if (!Child) {#<span style='font-weight: bold;'>#=SourceStr#</span>#} else { #<span>#=SourceStr#</span># }#",

            headerTemplate: kendo.template("# if (false) { # <span class='aecolumn-name'>Source</span><button class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(2)'></button><img src='Images/filter-icon.png' class='filter-icon'/> # } else { # <span class='aecolumn-name'>Source</span><button> class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(2)'></button><img src='Images/filter-icon-empty.png' style='width:18px; height:16px; margin-bottom: 3px'/> # } #")

        }, {

            field: "Message",

            title: culture.stringConst.Message,

            width: "15em",

            template: "#if (!Child) {#<span style='font-weight: bold;'>#=Message#</span>#} else { #<span>#=Message#</span># }#",

            headerTemplate: "<span class='aecolumn-name'>Message</span><button class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(3)'><img src='Images/filter-icon.png' class='filter-icon'/></button>"

        }, {

            field: "Severity",

            title: culture.stringConst.Severity,

            width: "5em",

            template: "#if (!Child) {#<span style='font-weight: bold;'>#=Severity#</span>#} else { #<span>#=Severity#</span># }#",

            headerTemplate: "<span class='aecolumn-name'>Severity</span><button class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(4)'><img src='Images/filter-icon.png' class='filter-icon'/></button>"

        }, {

            field: "Category",

            title: culture.stringConst.Category,

            width: "5em",

            template: "#if (!Child) {#<span style='font-weight: bold;'>#=Category#</span>#} else { #<span>#=Category#</span># }#",

            headerTemplate: "<span class='aecolumn-name'>Category</span><button class='panel-button' ng-mousedown='stopProp()' ng-click='openFilter(5)'><img src='Images/filter-icon.png' class='filter-icon'/></button>"

        }],

        scrollable: true,

        pageable: true,

        resizable: true,

        sortable: true

    };
```

Comment: You want to add button in header template by checking every data? That makes no sense. Please write `if` condition what you want to accomplish then i can help you

Comment: @dev_in_progress thank you for reply.
In header template I have button that will open kendo window. In this window I have input which works like filter. Basically what I need to say is: if (inputValue) {<button>Black button</button>}  else {<button>Grey button</button>} - to see that input is not empty if button is black, or if button is grey then input is empty.
That's the goal, to display one or another html element (or button) based on input value.
And if I force true or false value it works fine, but it won't accept my inputValue variable.